# Multi-Tenant Django Application

Tags: django, multi-tenant

Are there common patterns people use for creating multi-tenanted applications using Django. The built in "sites" framework seems like an option.  Are there other approaches people have had success with?

Comment: possible duplicate of [optimal architecture for multitenant application on django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194341/optimal-architecture-for-multitenant-application-on-django)

Answer (score 10):

Using the sites framework goes a long way towards providing a security guarantee to the "tenants", assuming you give each site instance a unique table.

On the other hand, it'll be a big hassle if you have a small number of tenants and you'll waste a huge amount of server resources since you'll need at least one server process per customer even if they aren't using the system.  If you have a large number of tenants it won't be quite as much hassle because you'll be forced to automate the solution regardless of your approach.

Putting a tenant foreign key in almost all your models will work just fine and Django's ORM makes it easy (easier?) to enforce security using [custom managers](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#id2).  The drawback is performance if you start getting hammered with lots of users, because there's no easy way to scale up.

If you do need to scale, I think the best solution *could be* a combination of both approaches.  Every model has a tenant foreignkey so databases can be shared but then you develop some mechanism at a higher level than Django to route customers into a site instance.  This lets you put really big tenants on their own databases with resources properly tuned just for them (e.g. the proper number of mod_wsgi daemons, number of database connections, memcache pool properly sized, etc.) and smaller tenants share common resources.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at https://github.com/bcarneiro/django-tenant-schemas
You'll only have one project instance and won't have to do many modifications in your code.

Comment: This is a nice approach if you want multiple DBs - lets you use multiple schemas in a single DB, for less overhead.  Requires PostgreSQL.  Django simple-tenant-schemas is also interesting.

Comment: I meant "if you want multiple DB-like approach but using schemas", sorry

Comment: Just wanted to +1 this answer as I have recently forked this project for a multi-tenant schema app and it is great! Well written, easily extensible, and nearly hassle free once implemented.