# optimal architecture for multitenant application on django

Tags: django, architecture, multi-tenant

I've been brooding over the right/optimal way to create a multitenancy application based
on Django.

Some explanation:

- Application can be used by several tenants (tenant1, tenant2, ...,).
- All tenant-individual data has to be secured against access of other tenants (and their users).
- Optionally tenants can create additional custom-fields for application-objects.
- Of course, underlying hardware limits number of tenants on one "system".

1) Separating each tenant by e.g. sub-domain and using tenant-specific databases in the underlying layer

2) Using some tenant-ID in the model to separate the tenant-data in the database

I am thinking about deployment-processes, performance of the system-parts (web-server(s), database-server(s), working-node(s),...)

What would be the best setup ?  Where are the pro's and con's?

What do you think?

Comment: If I could up-vote this a hundred times, I would.

Comment: Thx :-) Any ideas or additional aspects, I do not mentioned ?

Comment: Django has its Sites framework built-in, which I think can be extended to have better multitenant support. There needs to be a way to identify which "site" we need to pull content for from something in the request, instead of hard coding which site in settings.py

Comment: No-sql support can also make multitenant easier but, there's not currently a good way that I'm aware of to tell which shard a particular site's data sits on.

Comment: After looking into using the Sites framework, I came to the conclusion that its purpose is to make sharing data between different sites easier -- which is exactly the opposite of what you want for a multi-tenant app, for data security reasons.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

We built a multitenancy [platform](https://www.atizo.com/) using the following architecture. I hope you can find some useful hints.

- Each tenant gets sub-domain (t1.example.com)
- Using url rewriting the requests for the Django application are rewritten to something like example.com/t1
- All url definitions are prefixed with something like `(r'^(?P<tenant_id>[\w\-]+)`
- A [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware) processes and consumes the tenant_id and adds it to the request (e.g. request.tenant = 't1')
- Now you have the current tenant available in each view without specifying the tenant_id argument every view
- In some cases you don't have the request available. I solved this issue by binding the tenant_id to the current thread (similar to the [current language](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py) using `threading.local` )
- Create decorators (e.g a tenant aware `login_required`), middlewares or factories to protect views and select the right models
- Regarding to the databases I used two different scenarios:

  - Setup multiple databases and configure a [routing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#automatic-database-routing) according to current tenant. I used this first but switched to one database after about one year. The reasons were the following:

    - We didn't need a high secure solution to separate the data
    - The different tenants used almost all the same models
    - We had to manage a lot of databases (and didn't built an easy update/migration process)
  - Use one database with some simple mapping tables for i.e. users and different models. To add additional and tenant specific model fields we use [model inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance).

Regarding the environment we use the following setup:

- [Nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/)
- [uWSGI](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/)
- PostgreSQL
- [Memcached](http://memcached.org/)

From my point of view this setup has the following pro's and con's:

Pro:

- One application instance knowing the current tenant
- Most parts of the project don't have to bother with tenant specific issues
- Easy solution for sharing entities between all tenants (e.g. messages)

Contra:

- One quite large database
- Some very similar tables due to the model inheritance
- Not secured on the database layer

Of course the best architecture strongly depends on your requirements as number of tenants, the delta of your models, security requirements and so on.

**Update**: As we reviewed our architecture, I suggest to *not* rewrite the URL as indicated in point 2-3. I think a better solutions is to put the `tenant_id` as a Request Header and extract (point 4) the `tenant_id` out of the request with something like `request.META.get('TENANT_ID', None)`. This way you get neutral URLs and it's much easier to use Django built-in functions (e.g. `{% url ...%}` or `reverse()`) or external apps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. For the the designated application clear and secure separation of data is very important. I also think that about 70% of the models are the same for all tenants.

Comment: Then I suggest you to use a multiple database setup with automatic routing. I would use [south](http://south.aeracode.org/) to manage the databases as they now support multiple databases.

Comment: Thx. I prefer multiple database-setup actually, cause separation is clearer and shifting tenants to other db-server might be easier... south is already placed on my technology-stack for migrating-tasks...

Comment: Is this solution still actual? I read in different places that one should not rely on threading.local (anymore).

Comment: How did u did first point (Each tenant gets sub-domain (t1.example.com)).. how to achieve it in local machine and on production server ?

Comment: @RetoAebersold Do you need to maintain different versions simultaneously?

Answer (score 4):

Here are some pointers to related discussions:

- [Django ticket #15089](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15089): "contrib.sites and multitenancy"
- [Discussion on Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/django-developers/4jw79p76uUo/7gduK9rHeosJ%5d), see esp. Jari Pennanen's solution at the end
- the [patch introducing threadlocals-based multi-tenancy](https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/commit/a38ba5a7912402ca90524b00bf6f2254c1e2b439) in Mezzanine; see esp. `mezzanine.utils.sites.current_site_id`, `mezzanine.core.models.SiteRelated` and `mezzanine.core.request`
- the [django-simple-multitenant](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-simple-multitenant) re-usable app on PyPI

Answer (score 1):

I recommend taking a look at https://github.com/bcarneiro/django-tenant-schemas. It will solve your problems a bit like Reto mentioned, except that it uses postgresql schemas.