# Use database depending on subdomain

Tags: django, django-orm

Is it OK to set the database name setting depending on subdomain for each request?

Something like this in a middleware:

```
from django.db import connection

company_name = ... # read the subdomain
connection.settings_dict['NAME'] = 'db_' + company_name
```

Comment: This is not going to work like this.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not OK.

Are you trying to make a multi-tenant application? Look at this question:

- [optimal architecture for multitenant application on django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194341/optimal-architecture-for-multitenant-application-on-django)

See also the [sites framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/) and [multiple databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/) (specially [routers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#using-routers), "[Manually selecting a database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#manually-selecting-a-database)" and "[Exposing multiple databases in Django's admin interface](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#exposing-multiple-databases-in-django-s-admin-interface)".