# Implementing Multitenancy Using Namespaces (Python 3+)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

How to implement multitenancy in GAE using namespaces?

We can implement using [`namespace_manager`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/multitenancy/multitenancy) in Python 2.7 but there is no documentation available on how to use it in Python 3.7.

Is there any other approach to achieve multitenancy in GAE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Namespaces API is only supported in the Python 2.7 runtime. If you need a multi-tenant app in the Python 3.7 runtime, you'll need to implement it via your web framework of choice.

For example, see ["optimal architecture for multitenant application on django
"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194341/optimal-architecture-for-multitenant-application-on-django).

Comment: Hi, is there a way we can implement tenant specific separation at datastore level for NDB without using namespace manager and web framework ?

Answer (score 0):

Datastore supports multitenancy directly, other Google Cloud services do not support on GAE in python 3.