# Different Django Interfaces for Different user Groups

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have different user groups based on functionality: customer support, editors...etc

I want to use the same user system and database, but I want to have different interfaces (login, functionality, sub domain) for the different groups that I have, separate from the normal user website interface and login.

How would you do it?

Comment: The simple answer is that your view function checks the logged-in user and dispatches to group-specific handler views.

Comment: @AdamKG What about using separate subdomains and the login functionality since their group is not yet determined?

Comment: Your login view would check request.get_host() to dispatch instead. If the subdomain is group-specific, you'd want your dispatching views to check request.get_host(), then verify that the user is in the appropriate group, and finally dispatch to the "actual" view.

Comment: @AdamKG I can't leave the question open like that, and a comment is not an answer. Would you post it as a complete answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Just close the question - there's already more-fleshed-out examples. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194341/optimal-architecture-for-multitenant-application-on-django http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106557/multi-tenant-django-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using request.get_host() to provide different interfaces for each subdomain, and check in login for the correct group type of the would-be-logged-in user.